# SMARTGWT, menu item width not changing

Tags: smartgwt

I am using a MenuItem in my application but its showing all over the page , please have a look at the attachment , i am trying for hours and searched for but this width is not reducing ,
I am using the demo application of SmartGWT , using its code but i cant figure out whats the issue

any idea

thanks
[image]

code snippet:

```
                  itemListMenu = new Menu();  
    itemListMenu.setCellHeight(22); 
    MenuItem detailsMenuItem = new MenuItem("Show Details");  
    detailsMenuItem.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
        public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {  
            searchItemDetails.selectTab(0);  
            searchItemDetails.updateDetails();  
        }  
    });  

    MenuItem editMenuItem = new MenuItem("Edit Item");  
    editMenuItem.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.menu.events.ClickHandler() {  
        public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {  
            searchItemDetails.selectTab(1);  
            searchItemDetails.updateDetails();  
        }  
    });  

    MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete Item");  
    deleteMenuItem.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.menu.events.ClickHandler() {  
        public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {  
            userGrid.removeSelectedData();  
            searchItemDetails.clearDetails(null);  
        }  
    });  


    itemListMenu.setData(detailsMenuItem, editMenuItem, deleteMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we have a look at the code of the menu itself, did you set its width?

I tried your code

```
static void testMenu(){
     Menu itemListMenu = new Menu();  
        itemListMenu.setCellHeight(22); 
        MenuItem detailsMenuItem = new MenuItem("Show Details");  
        detailsMenuItem.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.menu.events.ClickHandler() {  
            public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {  

            }  
        });  

        MenuItem editMenuItem = new MenuItem("Edit Item");  
        editMenuItem.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.menu.events.ClickHandler() {  
            public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {  

            }  
        });  

        MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete Item");  
        deleteMenuItem.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.menu.events.ClickHandler() {  
            public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {  

            }  
        });  


        itemListMenu.setData(detailsMenuItem, editMenuItem, deleteMenuItem); 
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(itemListMenu);
}
```

Everyrything is fine, the width without doing anything correspond to the length of the longest item. So to which container did you add your menu?.

Comment: edited the code above , thats all i am dong with menuItem , i am not doing anything with the width , also tried to change width size , but no luck

Comment: thanks for your help , as in the code above by me , I am not adding it anywhere,  if i add it in some VPanel or some thing , then where will i add that vpanel

Comment: The RootPanel in my case  is the mainContainer if you want your Menu to be a member of A VLayout you add this VLayout to the parent container which could be the RootPanel for example. Besides with smartgwt your are not obliged to use thie rootpanel, you can simply invoke the draw method on your root widget (in this case you VLayout).